# Remove Item from Listbox which is not matching in Excel macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to remove an item from Listbox, where following criteria matches.
I have a sheet called "Data", i have three columns, one is Username and second one is Date and third one is Status.
I have data like below:

```
A Column ------ B Column ------ C Column 
John     ------ 09/08/2015 ---- Publish 
Marie    ------ 17/08/2015 ---- Publish 
John     ------ 08/08/2015 ---- Hold
```

I have written one code to load all names to Listbox like below

```
ListBox2.clear
j = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Sheets("Data").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ListBox2.clear
Dim myList As Collection
Dim myRange As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim myVal As Variant
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Set myRange = ws.Range("A2", ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
Set myList = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For Each myCell In myRange.Cells
myList.Add myCell.Value, CStr(myCell.Value)
Next myCell
On Error GoTo 0
For Each myVal In myList
ListBox2.AddItem myVal
Next myVal
```

The code will load all items to listbox. But now my problem is i have calender, when i select data, it should load only item which date i selected and status is hold, So from my example if i select "08/08/2015" it should show only John, I have used below code to remove item,

```
   For k = j To 1 Step -1
    If Format(Sheets("Data").Cells(k, "B"), "dd/mm/yyyy") <> Format(Calendar1.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy") Then
        For i = ListBox2.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If ListBox2.List(i) = Sheets("Data").Cells(k, "A").Value Then
            ListBox2.RemoveItem i
            End If
        Next
    End If
  Next k
```

Its removing all data because John appeared in another date, Any other code we can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made small modification to your removing code. Try as follow:

```
Dim validName As String

For k = j To 1 Step -1
    If Format(Sheets("Data").Cells(k, "B"), "dd/mm/yyyy") = Format(Calendar1.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy") Then
        validName = Sheets("Data").Cells(k, "A")
        Exit For
    End If
Next k

For i = ListBox2.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If ListBox2.List(i) <> validName Then
        ListBox2.RemoveItem i
    End If
Next
```